# Magento 2 is not generating the db_schema_whitelist.json file via CLI

Tags: magento2.3

I’m updating a module to Magento 2.3 and need to migrate the old setup install scripts to the new `db_schema.xml` file (the new declarative schema). The `db_schema.xml` file was correctly generated after running:

`php bin/magento setup:install --convert-old-scripts=1`

But now I need to generate the `db_schema_whitelist.json` file and running the following command does nothing:

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=[module_name]
```

I followed all the steps outlined in the [docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/migration-commands.html) and checked the permissions of the `etc` folder.

But the result is always the same: no errors, no response, nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found my own answer. Turns out the `db_schema.xml` file generated automatically by Magento had an error. The line that declares the name of the table was missing the `resource` value.

This is how the  tag was generated after running the CLI command:

```
<table name="my_table_name" resource="" engine="innodb" comment="My Table Comment">
```

And this is how it should be:

```
<table name="my_table_name" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="My Table Comment">
```

`resource` should contain the database shard on which to install the table. This value must be default, quote, or sales. In my case, adding `default` did the trick.

### Edit (04/25/2019):

Whenever the `db_whitelist_schema.json` file is not created automatically when running the `bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Vendor_Modulename` command you can safely assume there’s an error in the `etc/db_schema.xml` file of your module.

Since the terminal won’t return an error msg to help you fix the issue, you can resort to the following hack to discover the missing piece in your db_schema file.

1) Open the following core file: `vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/SchemaConfig.php`

2) Locate the getDeclarationConfig() method and add a try-catch like this:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getDeclarationConfig()
{
    try {
        $schema = $this->schemaFactory->create();
        $data = $this->readerComposite->read(FileResolverByModule::ALL_MODULES);
        $this->declarativeSchemaBuilder->addTablesData($data['table']);
        $schema = $this->declarativeSchemaBuilder->build($schema);
        return $schema;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/schema.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

3) Now run the `bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist`

4) Check for any errors in `var/log/schema.log`

5) Rinse and repeat until you fix all the errors in your db_schema.xml file

6) Don’t forget to remove the temporary changes you made to the core file!

Comment: Great post @Daniel Kratohvil!

Comment: @Daniel Kratohvil - Great answer . Like a way to find out the error in db_schema.xml file.

Comment: Thanks for this very good answer, nice to know why whitelist `db_schema.xml` sometimes are not generated.  Recent versions (M2.3.5) seems to have slightly better error reporting when trying to generate whitelist, (unique keys)... but not everything reports immediately.

Answer (score 9):

The `db_schema_whitelist.json` will also not be created if you enter a wrong module name or have any typo in the CLI command:

`php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Vendor_Module`

In this case, the command will not throw any errors in cli.

Answer (score 7):

Before run below command for generate db_schema_whitelist.json

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Vendor_Module
```

you have to enable module in which your "db_schema.xml" file exists by running below CLI command

```
bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Module
```

and of course clean cache.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the OP's own answer EDIT, I propose a more global way to debug executing the `bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Vendor_Modulename` command, which should work for all kind of error, not only ones about errors in `db_schema.xml`:

1. Open the file that defines the `setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist` command in `vendor/magento/module-developer/Console/Command/TablesWhitelistGenerateCommand.php`
2. Locate the `execute(...)` method, and add the following code:

```php
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
{
    // ...
    try {
        // Original code
    } catch (ConfigurationMismatchException $e) {
        // Original code
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // ADD FOLLOWING LINE:
        $output->writeln('<error>' . $e->getMessage() . '</error>');
        return \Magento\Framework\Console\Cli::RETURN_FAILURE;
    }
    // ...
}
```

> This way, you won't have to manually check a log file, as the error will be displayed in the CLI.

(In my opinion, this simple line of code should already be in the code base, anyway...)

EDIT: Actually, this exact line of code has been [added in the core code](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/f0ae717818562e83e86cdc8404ade855e44ae968#diff-1319f591366e5096dd9fc8529e65a7c3). I was simply not up-to-date...

Answer (score 0):

One really quick thing I've found worth checking. If Magento 2 is not generating your `db_schema_whitelist.json`, make sure your module is actually enabled by checking `bin/magento mod:status module` where module is the name of your module, and then `bin/magento mod:ena module` to enable your module. It's super easy to create a module and forget to enable it before trying to use it. This issue applies to more than just `db_schema_whitelist.json`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

For me It only works after I run s:up first then the module installed and after that the whitelist json was added just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @Danial is great but still if it is not working then check the below point as well

1- Check if module is enable or enable it using

```
bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Module
```

2- Check if you have the correct permission, maybe the file is not generating because you do not have the required permission.

Answer (score 0):

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Ced_Commerce
```