# can not create db_schema_whitelist.json file in magento 2.4.4

Tags: magento2.4, db-schema

I have issue to create custom mysql table from xml schema.

i have create app/code/Vendor_Name/Module_Name/etc/db_schema.xml

**db_schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="test_table" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Test blog table">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="entity_id" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true"
                comment="Entity ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="title" length="70" nullable="false" comment="Title"/>
        <column xsi:type="timestamp" name="created_at" on_update="false" nullable="false" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
                comment="Creation Time"/>
        <column xsi:type="timestamp" name="updated_at" on_update="true" nullable="false" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
                comment="Update Time"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="entity_id"/>
        </constraint>
   </table>
</schema>
```

After this i have execute CLI with no error but can't create db_schema_whitelist.json in ***Vendor_Name/Module_name/etc*** folder

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=VendorName_ModuleName
```

My vendor_Name/Module_Name is already ***enable***

What i do please help!!!

Comment: Does the CLI user has write access to VendorName/ModuleName/etc folder?

Comment: Yes it has full access

Comment: Please specify Magento version, I've tested this fragment with 2.4.3 and 2.4.4 and it works properly. To be sure you have properly configured extension. Alternative is try to check comments from https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255583/magento-2-is-not-generating-the-db-schema-whitelist-json-file-via-cli (add debug to schema generation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your db_schema.xml is wrong. It has duplicate entries for **'title'** column. Remove it and retry. It should work.

This `db_schema.xml` is working fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="test_table" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Test blog table">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="entity_id" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true"
                comment="Entity ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="title" length="70" nullable="false" comment="Title"/>
        <column xsi:type="timestamp" name="created_at" on_update="false" nullable="false" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
                comment="Creation Time"/>
        <column xsi:type="timestamp" name="updated_at" on_update="true" nullable="false" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
                comment="Update Time"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="entity_id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

This is the generated `db_schema_whitelist.json` file

```
{
    "test_table": {
        "column": {
            "entity_id": true,
            "title": true,
            "created_at": true,
            "updated_at": true
        },
        "constraint": {
            "PRIMARY": true
        }
    }
}
```

Magento CLI command was

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=Vendor_Module
```

If you are still getting an error, then it should be something else. Post the error here.

Comment: Thanks that's right error in code about <title> tag but still getting same issue

Comment: Check the edited answer.

Comment: Ok I will try and give feedback

Comment: Thanks that's work...